# Is there any way to find the centre of a graph in Neo4j or NetworkX?

Tags: python, neo4j, networkx, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I am new to graph theory. Currently I am working with Neo4j, and I need to find centre nodes in a subgraph for analysis. Is there any way to find central nodes in either Neo4j or NetworkX?

Comment: What is a center node?

Comment: here center node means those node which eccentricity is equal to radius

Comment: Apparently, networkx does indeed have such a [function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/algorithms/distance_measures.html#center).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in NetworkX using [`networkx.algorithms.distance_measure.center()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.distance_measures.center.html), which returns a list of central nodes in the graph. Below is an example which plots central nodes in red.

**Example Code:**

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.distance_measures import center

# Set up graph
G = nx.barbell_graph(5, 5)

# Get position using spring layout
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# Get center node(s)
c = center(G)

# Draw non-central nodes & all edges
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=set(G.nodes)-set(c))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)

# Draw central nodes in red
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=c, node_color='r')

# Draw labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
```

**Output:**

```
G = nx.barbell_graph(5, 5)
```

[image]

```
G = nx.complete_graph(6)
```

[image]